# How to combine consecutive number ranges

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for a neat way to combine consecutive number ranges in a single select statement.

Say my table has these records:

```
first_number    last_number
0   9
10  19
20  29
40  49
50  59
70  79
```

Then output shall be as follows:

```
first_number    last_number
0   29
40  59
70  79
```

This is what I've come up with:

```
select first_number, last_number_of_range
from
(
  select 
    first_number, is_continuing, is_continued,
    nvl(lead (last_number,1,null) over (order by first_number), last_number) as last_number_of_range
  from
  (
    select *
    from
    (
      select first_number, last_number, 
       case when lag (last_number,1,null) over (order by first_number) + 1 = first_number then 1 else 0 end as is_continuing, 
       case when lead (first_number,1,null) over (order by last_number) - 1 = last_number then 1 else 0 end as is_continued
      from 
      (
        select 0 as first_number, 9 as last_number from dual
        union all
        select 10 as first_number, 19 as last_number from dual
        union all
        select 20 as first_number, 29 as last_number from dual
        union all
        select 40 as first_number, 49 as last_number from dual
        union all
        select 50 as first_number, 59 as last_number from dual
        union all
        select 70 as first_number, 79 as last_number from dual
      )
    )
    where is_continuing = 0 or is_continued = 0 -- remove all but first and last of consecutive records
  )
)
where is_continuing = 0 -- now at last remove those records that gave us the last_number_of_range
;
```

This works fine. Only, it looks so complicated for so small a task. I would be interested to know wether there is a much more straight way than mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
with T1 as (
  select 
    row_number() over (order by first_number) RNum, 
    first_number, 
    last_number 
  From yourtable
)
,T (RNUM, first_number, last_number, CNT) as (
    select T1.*, 1 CNT from T1 where RNum=1
    union all
    SELECT b.RNUM, b.first_number, b.last_number, (case when b.first_number=T.last_number+1 then t.CNT 
                        else T.CNT+1 end) CNT
    from T1 b INNER JOIN T on b.RNum=T.RNum+1
)
select 
   min(first_number) as first_number,
    max(last_number) as last_number
From T group by T.CNT
```

[SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0c64/1)

Comment: Hi techdo, thank you for your answer. This looks really good. However, I am pretty sure that Oracle doesn't support recursive with clauses. (Doesn't work in my 10g at least and I found nothing to indicate that Oracle changed this in 11g or 12c.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: recursive CTEs were introduced in Oracle 11.2 (which the SQL Fiddle demo clearly demonstrates): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2077142

Comment: Ah, sorry, you are right. Thank you, I am marking your answer as correct.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach, which will give you desired output.

```
select min(first_number)  as first_number
     , max(last_number)   as last_number
 from ( 
        select first_number
              , last_number
              , sum(grp) over(order by first_number) as grp
           from ( select first_number
                       , last_number
                       , case
                           when first_number <>
                                   lag(last_number) 
                                     over(order by first_number) + 1
                           then 1
                           else 0
                         end as grp
                     from t1 )
       )
group by grp
order by 1
```

Result:

```
FIRST_NUMBER LAST_NUMBER
------------ -----------
           0          29
          40          59
          70          79
```

[**SQLFiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d799/21)

Comment: @Ramblin'Man Yes, it wont do any harm here, though, but it seems redundant to use it - simple `max` will be enough. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Actually, i was looking for some explanation on FIRST/LAST function. I don't understand when are they useful. Maybe I should ask a separate question on this.

Comment: @Ramblin'Man `Keep dense_rank first[last]` allows you to apply aggregate(or analytic) function to the set of data that were ranked as first or last according to the ordering rule. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions065.htm#i1000901)

Comment: Hi Nicholas, thanks for the answer. But sorry, no, I am not talking about increments of ten. Just adjacent ranges. Could also be 0 to 10 then 11 to 12 then 13 to 50. This would have to be recognised as actaually one range of 0 to 50.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, I misunderstood the question. It will require minor modification. Answer has been updated.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, yes this works. A great idea to use a running total to mark distinct ranges. Now I got two good answers to my question. I have already marked the other as accepted, so I am given yours only a thumbs up. Sorry. I guess I like both answers equally.

Answer (score 0):

An old thread, but I have another solution... worked well in my tests and it seems very simple.

Uncommented one:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(r2.first_number) AS first_number, 
  r1.last_number 
FROM <table> AS r1
INNER JOIN <table> AS r2 ON 1=1
  AND r2.first_number < r1.last_number
LEFT JOIN <table> AS r3 ON 1=1
  AND r3.last_number  >= r1.last_number + 1
  AND r3.first_number <= r1.last_number + 1
LEFT JOIN <table> AS r4 ON 1=1
  AND r4.last_number  >= r2.first_number - 1
  AND r4.first_number <= r2.first_number - 1
WHERE 1=1
  and r3.first_number IS NULL
  and r4.first_number IS NULL
GROUP BY r1.last_number
;
```

Commented one:

```
SELECT 
  -- getting a first_number 
  -- lesser than the 
  -- maximum first_number available
  -- makes this maximum one
  -- an overlap...
  MAX(r2.first_number) first_number, 
  r1.last_number 
FROM <table> r1
INNER JOIN <table> r2 ON 1=1
  -- join the data so 
  -- for  a last_number  in r1 you can
  -- find a first_number in r2 that is
  -- lesser than its value, as 
  -- no first_number should be
  -- greater than (or equals?) a last_number
  AND r2.first_number < r1.last_number
LEFT JOIN <table> r3 ON 1=1
  -- matches when another range 
  -- overlaps last_number from r1
  AND r3.last_number  >= r1.last_number + 1
  AND r3.first_number <= r1.last_number + 1
LEFT JOIN <table> r4 ON 1=1
  -- matches when another range 
  -- overlaps first_number from r2
  AND r4.last_number  >= r2.first_number - 1
  AND r4.first_number <= r2.first_number - 1
WHERE 1=1
  -- get rows 
  -- with no overlaps on last_number and
  -- with no overlaps on first_number
  and r3.first_number IS NULL
  and r4.first_number IS NULL
GROUP BY r1.last_number
;
```